# Finding coordinates of pixels inside a countour

Tags: python, image, image-processing, contour

I want to find the coordinates of the pixels inside a contour or a border.
Here B represent the coordinates of the contour with dimensions 38*2 per example(B is an array of the coordiantes x y of the countour pts)

```
coordinates = []

for i in range (B.shape[0]):
    for j in range (B.shape[0]):
        if B[i, 1] == B[j,1]:
            a, b = j, B[j,1]
            if B[i,0]<= B[a,0]:
                for k in range (int(B[i,0]), int(B[a,0]+1)):
                    coordinates.append([k,b])
            else:
                for m in range (int(B[a,0]), int(B[i,0]+1)):
                    coordinates.append([m , b])
```

But it's clearly not the right way to do it since it passed the coordinates of the initial image.

Comment: It would be useful if you can give more information about 'B', like how did you obtained it and which libraries are you using. I think that what you would like to perform is an image segmentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation). For this operation, there are optimized functions in different libraries.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question: why not just registering the coordinates of the the lower-left pixel of the border and subtract it to initial coordinates ?